# log4j logging once after tomcat restart

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I try to log some webservice requests and responses but log4j is logging once for first session. After first session finished, second session requests and responses are not written to log file.

I restarted tomcat but same problem occurs after every restart.

Here is property file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN"    "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
        value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="Connector"  class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/Connector.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
        value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="com.connector">
    <appender-ref ref="Connector" />
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```